# Add a shape to word document by overlapping with present paragraphs

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am trying to build a document using apache POI. The starting page of the document should have a rectangular shape(vertical) to the left of the document[image: output should be like this]

Before asking for help let me tell you what all I tried. I have tried to create a paragraph and add this shape to it(I have taken the screenshot of the shape and tried to add it to the paragraph). But there are multiple paragraphs in the page, so the image is overlapping the remaining paragraphs and giving me the shape for the paragraph[image: Overlapped shape]

I want the similar shape to be on the left side of the document from start of the page to the end of the page. I am new to web application development and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Really a shape? The better approach would be a thick left [border line for each paragraph](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-border-to-some-text-dc90dbd4-11ec-4859-91b7-a41a38e73cd3) or a thick left [page border](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-border-to-a-page-82c2078a-af86-4f5a-ae2a-517164ba5801).

Comment: Hi Axel Richter. Thanks for your reply. I have checked both of your links that you have provided. The first link talks about how to set border line for each paragraph. I do not need borders for the paragraph for now. The second link talks about setting the border across the page. However i want a border only to the left side of the document as shown in the first image. Any help would be appreciated and thanks for commenting.

Comment: For the borders setting left border only also is possible.

Comment: Hi Axel Richter. Thanks again. I could now see that we can add left border to the first page of the document. Would you be kind enough to guide me how to draw left border to the first page of the word document? Any insights for you would be helpful. Thank you Axel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using shapes in Apache POI `XWPF` is not really supported. And there are many compatibility problems using shapes in Microsoft Word. The most compatible approach will be using VML-shapes. This is what Microsoft Word had used up to Word 2007.

To solve what you seems to want, I would take the VML-shape outside the document body into the first page header. So the shape is outside the document body and so protected from changes within the document body.

Minimal complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class CreateWordHeaderFirstPageWithShape {
    
 private static void createRectShape(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String fillcolor, String style) throws Exception {
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup ctGroup = com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
  com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTRect ctRect = ctGroup.addNewRect();
  ctRect.setStyle(style);
  ctRect.setFillcolor(fillcolor);
     
  org.w3c.dom.Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture ctPicture = 
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (
   XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordHeaderFirstPageWithShape.docx");
   ) {
       
   // create header
   XWPFHeader header = doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
   XWPFParagraph paragraph = header.createParagraph();
   createRectShape(paragraph, 
    "#FFB000", 
    "position:absolute;left:-10pt;top:30pt;width:10pt;height:700pt");

   // the body content
   paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
   XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
   run.setText("The Body... lorem ipsum...");
   
   paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
   run = paragraph.createRun();  
   run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);

   paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  
   doc.write(out);
   
  }
 }
}
```

To get some API documentation for this, download `poi-ooxml-full-5.*-sources.jar` and unzip this.  It contains `/com/microsoft/schemas/vml`. Then do `javadoc` from the sources in `-subpackages com`.

Comment: Hi Axel Richter. This is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Axel Richter. Any chance of creating a shape without paragraph? I am trying to draw a shape that starts at the end of header and ends at the start of footer. The above code that you have provided works fine but the shape color is slightly light since we created a paragraph in the header. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bharath Naidu Yenumula: "but the shape color is slightly light since we created a paragraph in the header": It is light because and as long the header is not focused. It is light to show that it is not focused. It is light only in GUI. It will be normal colored elsewhere, when printed, exported to PDF, ...

Comment: Hi  @Axel Richter. Is there any way to remove the black border around the shape in the above code? Thanks.

Comment: @Bharath Naidu Yenumula: Have you tried to get `javadoc` from `/com/microsoft/schemas/vml`? If so you will find `com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTRect` has a property `stroked`: `ctRect.setStroked(org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.sharedTypes.STTrueFalse.FALSE);`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shape for what you seem to want will be very impractical. A shape must be anchored to some element and will shift if this element shifts. Also a shape will either be before or behind the text. So either text will overlap the shape or the shape will overlap text.

The better approach is using a left page border as shown in [Add a border to a page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-border-to-a-page-82c2078a-af86-4f5a-ae2a-517164ba5801).

Unfortunately Apache POI does not support this using the high level `XWPF` classes. But a `*.docx` is simply a ZIP archive and so one can simple unzip that file to have a look into it. So create a page border using Microsoft Word GUI. Then save as `*.docx`. Then open as ZIP archive and look into `/word/document.xml`. You will see something like:

```
...
<w:sectPr>
 <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
 <w:pgMar w:left="1440" w:right="1440"/>
 ...
 <w:pgBorders w:display="firstPage">
  <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="48" w:space="4" w:color="FFB000"/>
 </w:pgBorders>
 ...
</w:sectPr>
...
```

This are section properties having page settings and page border settings.

Now you can create that using the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes.

To get some API documentation for this, download `poi-ooxml-full-5.*-sources.jar`, unzip this and do `javadoc` from the sources.

Minimal complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordPageBorder {
     
 static void setDefaultPageSettings(XWPFDocument doc, int pageWidth, int pageHeight, int pageLeftMargin , int pageRightMargin) {
  CTDocument1 document1 = doc.getDocument();
  CTBody body = document1.getBody();
  CTSectPr sectPr = body.getSectPr();
  if (sectPr == null) sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  if (sectPr.isSetPgSz()) sectPr.unsetPgSz();
  CTPageSz pageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz();
  pageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(pageWidth));
  pageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(pageHeight));
  CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
  pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(pageLeftMargin)); 
  pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(pageRightMargin));
 }

 static void setLeftPageBorderFirstPage(XWPFDocument doc, int size, String color) {
  CTDocument1 document1 = doc.getDocument();
  CTBody body = document1.getBody();
  CTSectPr sectPr = body.getSectPr();
  if (sectPr == null) return; // there must be section properties (page settings) already
  if (sectPr.isSetPgBorders()) sectPr.unsetPgBorders();
  CTPageBorders pageBorders = sectPr.addNewPgBorders();
  pageBorders.setDisplay​(STPageBorderDisplay.FIRST_PAGE); //LibreOffice will not support this
  CTPageBorder pageBorder = pageBorders.addNewLeft();
  pageBorder.setVal​(STBorder.SINGLE);
  pageBorder.setSz​(BigInteger.valueOf(size));
  pageBorder.setSpace​(BigInteger.valueOf(4));
  pageBorder.setColor​(color);
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  int TWIPS_PER_INCH = 1440;
  
  try (
   XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordPageBorder.docx");
   ) {
       
   int pageWidth = (int)Math.round(8.5 * TWIPS_PER_INCH); // page size letter
   int pageHeight = (int)Math.round(11 * TWIPS_PER_INCH); // page size letter
   int pageLeftMargin = (int)Math.round(1 * TWIPS_PER_INCH);
   int pageRightMargin = (int)Math.round(1 * TWIPS_PER_INCH);

   setDefaultPageSettings(doc, pageWidth, pageHeight, pageLeftMargin, pageRightMargin);
   
   setLeftPageBorderFirstPage(doc, 48, "FFB000");
   
   // the body content
   XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
   XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
   run.setText("The Body... lorem ipsum...");
   
   paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
   run = paragraph.createRun();  
   run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);

   paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  
   doc.write(out);
   
  }
 }
}
```